# In causal inference, is the usual unconfoundedness assumption interpreted to apply at the unit or covariate level?

Tags: causality, matching, observational-study

Suppose for each unit $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$, we have that

$(Y_i(1),Y_i(0))$ are the potential outcomes,

$Z_i$ is the treatment,

and

$X_i$ the covariates.

I have seen the following two formulations for unconfoundedness, and am wondering if they are perhaps the same or different:

$$
(Y_i(1),Y_i(0)) \perp Z_i \mid X_i \qquad \forall \ i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}
$$

and

$$
(Y_i(1),Y_i(0)) \perp Z_i \mid X_i=x \qquad \forall \ x \in \mathcal{X}
$$

That is, the first equation above states that given each unit's observed covariates $X_i$, the condition holds at the unit-level.

The second equation seems to state that at any given value of $x$ belonging to the covariate space $\mathcal{X}$, the condition will hold regardless of which unit we are considering. In some sense, it seems the second equation is stronger than the first.

Is there perhaps a difference in the two? Or are they one and the same?

Comment: Where have you seen the first one? The first one doesn't make sense.